# Get all records from JSON response

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm still kind of new to the Rest Assured API world.  I've read through as much documentation on https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-3---complex-parsing-and-validation as I can stand.

I have a response that looks like:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Result": [
    {
      "EmployeeId": "5661631",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "Home",
      "PhoneNumber": "9701234567",

    },
    {
      "EmployeeId": "5661631",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "mobile1",
      "PhoneNumber": "2531234567",

    },
    {
      "EmployeeId": "5661631",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "mobile2",
      "PhoneNumber": "8081234567",
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been struggling with how to get just the first record's PhoneNumber.

```
String responseBody= 
                given()
                    .relaxedHTTPSValidation().contentType("application/json")
                    .param("api_key", api_key).
                when()
                    .get("/api/employees/" + employeeId)
                    .andReturn().asString();

    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody).setRoot("Result");
    phoneNumber = jsonPath.getString("PhoneNumber");
```

I get all the phone numbers in this case:
phoneNumber = "[9701234567,2531234567,8081234567]"

How can I get just the first record? I'd rather not have to perform string operations to deal with the, "[".

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do,

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
phoneNumber = json.getJSONArray("Result").getJSONObject(0).getString("PhoneNumber");
```

Here, `0` indicates the first record in the JSON Array `Result`.

Comment: What library are you using for JSONObject?

Comment: This one is using `org.json`. But I think you can also use something like `Jackson` and achieve the same.

Comment: Its a valid solution and similar solutions can be implemented using Gson, Jackson etc but the code is already using 'rest-assured' and tagged as 'rest-assured', so I think using 'JsonPath' which is part of rest-assured is more appropriate.

Comment: @vinay I disagree with the fact that you should use a particular library because you already have it. If this would be the case then we shouldn't use any of the Guava libraries for `Lists` and `Maps` because Java already has it! And so on... I think what's more important is to evaluate the need and then choose a library.

Comment: I agree that we need to evaluate the need and choose a library. My point is that the code is written using 'rest-assured' API, so answer using 'rest-assured' API is more appropriate. If I have question in Guava API, I expect solution using Guava API and not something else.

Answer (score 2):

Because you know the index of the element you want to retrieve, you can use the following code:

```
JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
String phoneNumber = jsonPath.getString("Result[0].PhoneNumber");
```